# Application values get removed in android

Tags: android

I have written the code like below extends application, in my app even though my app is running in background some time the value changed as null or empty.

While app loads from background to foreground some time the values are not available. It's happening while app is in background for 15mins - 30mins

```
public class AppState extends Application {

    public static String UName= "Test";
    public static String Password = "Test@123";

    public static int SLIMIT = 0 ;
    public static String iTemname = "Item";

}
```

Comment: Please share your android manifest and code hox you call AppState

Comment: Is your app really running something in background(service or threads)?

Answer (score 1):

Android life cycle can be a little annoying to deal with.

When your application process is destroyed the static members will lose their values. So if you want to persist information, use shared preferences.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref